# How do you undo an operation in Argocd?

Tags: kubernetes, finalizer, argocd

Lets say you use [Argocd](https://argoproj.github.io/cd/) to deploy helm charts to Kubernetes. Things work great but you have a kubernetes resource [finalizer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/finalizers/) on a resource. Somebody deletes the resource and now Argo just waits in the state of 'Progressing' or 'Deleting'. It can't actually do the delete due to the finalizer. This is a good protection mechanism for very important files like aws iam files.

But I am hopeful somebody can help me figure out. Is there anyway to stop the operation given to argo and instead just let it sync again as normal? Maybe somebody made a mistake and the finalizer worked as intended. Instead of clearing the finalizer and dealing with the consequences. Can the consequences be prevented by undoing argocds operation?

Thank you

Comment: you will need to remove the finalizer to get it out of `progressing` - `kubectl patch <k8s-cr> <cr-name> --type json --patch='[ { "op": "remove", "path": "/metadata/finalizers" } ]'`

Comment: Hello, If the issue has been resolved and my answer has contributed to resolve your issue please up-vote/accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you need to delete the corresponding Argocd application or you need to roll back the deployment. If you delete the application it will remove all the resources created by the application and it will stop the operation. If you roll back to the previous version it will undo the changes you have made in the current deployment and bring all your resources to previous versions.
You can use Argo CD CLI argocd app rollback’  -r ’, to roll back to the particular version you want.

You can also roll back from Argo CD UI. If your finalizer is still present you need to manually remove the finalizer and then re-apply the resource definitions.

Please check this [document](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-rollouts/generated/kubectl-argo-rollouts/kubectl-argo-rollouts_undo/)

Comment: Thanks. Arent the argocd rollout it's own project?